# Javascript Filter returning two objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

ers,
I'm having some trouble with this algorithm.

I'm using Redux, though I don't think that is really relevant for this problem. Basically the console.log statement in this code returns only one object, just as it should, but the function A returns an array of the two objects (even the one that didn't pass the test in function C)

I separated the functions into 3 parts to see if that would help me fix it, but I couldn't figure it out still.

Any advice?

```
const A = (state) => {
  // looks through an array and passes down a resource
  return state.resources.locked.filter((resource) => {
    return B(state, resource);
  })
};
// looks through an array and passes down a building
const B = (state, resource) => {
  return state.bonfire.allStructures.filter((building) => {
    return C(building, resource);
  })
};
// checks if building name and resource requirment are the same, and if building is unlocked
// then returns only that one
const C = (building, resource) => {
  if (building.unlocked && building.name == resource.requires.structure) {
      console.log(resource);
      return resource;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample `state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `filter`, do realise that the callback functions you pass to it are expected to return a boolean value indicating whether a particular element needs to be filtered in or out.

But in your case, `B` does not return a boolean, but an array. And even when that array is empty (indicating no resource matches), such a value will not be considered false by `filter`, and so the corresponding resource will still occur in the array returned by `A`.

A quick fix: get the length of the array that is returned by `B`, and return that instead. Zero will be considered false:

```js
const A = (state) => {
  // looks through an array and passes down a resource
  return state.resources.locked.filter((resource) => {
    return B(state, resource).length;  /// <---- length!
  })
};
// looks through an array and passes down a building
const B = (state, resource) => {
  return state.bonfire.allStructures.filter((building) => {
    return C(building, resource);
  })
};
// checks if building name and resource requirement are the same, and if building
// is unlocked and then returns only that one
const C = (building, resource) => {
  if (building.unlocked && building.name == resource.requires.structure) {
      return resource;
  }
}

// Sample data. Only x matches.
var state = {
    resources: {
        locked: [{ // resource
            requires: {
                structure: 'x'
            }
        }, { // resource
            requires: {
                structure: 'y'
            }
        }]
    },
    bonfire: {
        allStructures: [{ // building
            unlocked: true,
            name: 'x'
        }, { // building
            unlocked: true,
            name: 'z'
        }]
    }
};

console.log(A(state));
```

But better would be to really return booleans at each place where they are expected. So `C` should just return the result of the condition, and `B` could use `some` instead of `filter`, which not only returns a boolean, but also stops looking further once a match is found. In `A` you can have the original code now, as you really want `A` to return data (not a boolean).

Note also that you can use the short-cut notation for arrow functions that only have an expression that is evaluated:

```js
  // looks through an array and passes down a resource
const A = state => state.resources.locked.filter( resource => B(state, resource) );
// looks through an array and passes down a building
  // Use .some instead of .filter: it returns a boolean
const B = (state, resource) => 
    state.bonfire.allStructures.some( building => C(building, resource) );
// checks if building name and resource requirment are the same, and if building 
// is unlocked and then returns only that one
  // Return boolean
const C = (building, resource) => building.unlocked 
                               && building.name == resource.requires.structure;
// Sample data. Only x matches.
var state = {
    resources: {
        locked: [{ // resource
            requires: {
                structure: 'x'
            }
        }, { // resource
            requires: {
                structure: 'y'
            }
        }]
    },
    bonfire: {
        allStructures: [{ // building
            unlocked: true,
            name: 'x'
        }, { // building
            unlocked: true,
            name: 'z'
        }]
    }
};
console.log(A(state));
```